# Postgres - How to use the AVG of the last number of rows and multiply it with another column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
date     | ratio | revenue  
---------|-------|-----------
03-30-18 | 1.2   | 918264
03-31-18 | 0.94  | 981247
04-01-18 | 1.1   | 957353
04-02-18 | 0.99  | 926274
04-03-18 | 1.05  |
04-04-18 | 0.97  | 
04-05-18 | 1.23  |
```

As you can see, 04-03-18 and beyond haven't happened yet so there is no revenue input for those days. But I have a ratio for those future days. I want to use the AVG revenue of the last 4 days that I *do* have and multiply it by the ratio to make future revenue predictions.

In result, I wish to have the following table:

```
date     | ratio | revenue  
---------|-------|-----------
03-30-18 | 1.2   | 918264
03-31-18 | 0.94  | 981247
04-01-18 | 1.1   | 957353
04-02-18 | 0.99  | 926274
04-03-18 | 1.05  | 993073.73
04-04-18 | 0.97  | 917410.97
04-05-18 | 1.23  | 1163314.94
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a need for window functions, so I would phrase this as:

```
select t.date, t.ratio, 
       coalesce(t.revenue, a.avg4 * ratio) as revenue
from t cross join
     (select avg(revenue) as avg4
      from (select t.*
            from t
            where t.revenue is not null
            order by date desc
            limit 4
           ) t
     ) a
order by date;
```

Comment: [SqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/be6f6/6). The query may be a bit faster than mine, I like this approach.

Answer (score 2):

You should calculate the average in an initial query and use the value for rows with nulls in `revenue`:

```
with the_avg as (
    select avg
    from (
        select 
            date, 
            revenue, 
            avg(revenue) over (order by date rows between 4 preceding and current row)
        from my_table
        ) s
    where revenue is null
    order by date
    limit 1
    )
select 
    date, 
    ratio, 
    case when revenue is not null then revenue
    else round(avg * ratio, 2) end as revenue
from my_table
cross join the_avg
order by date;
```

[SqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/be6f6/1)